# How to count records of an array with condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, loops, conditional-statements

i have e.g. a table "Employee" with

```
last_name :: character varying
handed_texts :: text[]
```

Where text is an own data-type with "("Date", title/not_exist)".

There could be x entries while x := ({}, 1,2,...)

Example:

```
jones , {"(2017-01-01, stars_in_univ)", "(2017-01-01, not_exist)",   "(2017-01-02, unemployed ants)"}
tomes , {"(2017-01-01, not_exist)", "(2017-01-08, shared_minds)"}
```

My Problem now: i want to count the existing texts for each name.
I tried e.g. something like that:

```
SELECT last_name, handed_texts,
       CASE
           WHEN handed_texts IS NULL THEN 0
           ELSE
               FOREACH i IN ARRAY handed_texts
               DECLARE c integer;
               SET c = 0;
               LOOP
                   IF i NOT LIKE '%not_exist%' THEN c+1 ELSE c END IF
                 return c
              END LOOP
      END AS counted_texts
FROM employee
```

I know the declaration is totally wrong, but i couldn't find any way to declare a variable in a way that my system accepts so i just wrote it at the place i think it should be declared.
The other way i tried to count was to make a new array where i just put the correct/wanted record in and use array_length, but that seems to be even more catastrophal than the e.g above.

Comment: It's not a good idea to define your own data type with the same name as an existing built-in one

Comment: Thx, that's right. But i found for a short example nothing good so fast.
Maybe just call it protocol with same definition ... .

Answer (score 1):

I can't promise it's efficient, but if you unnest and re-aggregate, it seems this would be possible:

```
with exploded as (
  select last_name, unnest (handed_texts) as handed
  from employee
)
select
  last_name, array_agg (handed) as handed_texts
from exploded
where
  handed not like '%not_exist%'
group by last_name
```

That said, if you changed handed_texts to its own table like this:

```
create table handed_texts (
   last_name varchar,
   title_date date,
   title_name text
)
```

And did a join on last_name, I think it might provide a cleaner solution all around.

Comment: It seems to be a good idea, but the/my problem here is, the possibility of unknown. so i should make a CASE where to fill a 0 for {} in. That will mybe work.
Thx.

And yes, it would be a good idea to change that like you wrote, but it is given and i have to work/deal with it ... .

Comment: Try the suggestion on your data and let me know.  Again, I don't promise it's fast, but I do think it's scalable.

Comment: I figgured out the problem for now:
The UNNEST does work, no Problem.
Then:
last_name    handed
jones       (2017-01-01,stars_in_univ)
jones       (2017-01-01,not_exist)
jones       (2017-01-02,unemployed ants)
tomes       (2017-01-01,not_exist)
tomes       (2017-01-08, shared_minds)

when i now use 
WHERE handed NOT LIKE '%not_exist%'
there is the ERROR  operator does not exist: boolean !~~ unknown at character XXX
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts

It does not really help me at the moment.
But thx so far

Comment: That's curious...  can you post the DDL for your table?  You said that the `handed_texts` column is `text[]` -- an array of `text`, right?  When you run the subquery (with the unnest) in PgAdmin, what does it list as the datatype for the column named `handed`?  I don't see how any of my code could produce a boolean!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to string, and the use standard LIKE construction:

```
select last_name, count(*) 
from (select last_name, array_to_string(handed_texts,',','') t
      from employee e2) a
where a.t like '%not_exist%
group by last_name;
```

Sorry, Missed in translation from my [rextester](http://rextester.com/RHA70056)

Comment: SELECT last_name, handed_texts, count(*) as num
FROM (SELECT last_name, handed_texts, array_to_string(handed_texts,',','') t
      FROM employee) a
WHERE a.t NOT LIKE '%not_exist%'
GROUP BY last_name, handed_texts, count(*) as num

My count is always 1. But i found my mistake at the example and question above and make a better example with the handed_texts - array and make the question more precise.
First: at the array there can be x entries x := ({}, 1,2,....)
I need the count of the handed_texts for each name itself.

Answer (score 0):

The [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html) function may be useful here. You can use it like this:

```
SELECT e.id, COUNT(texts.id)
FROM employee AS e
LEFT JOIN (
    -- this "unfolds" all arrays as if they were a single table of all texts of all employees
    SELECT id, UNNEST(handed_texts) AS handed_texts
    FROM employee
) AS texts ON texts.id = e.id
WHERE ... -- any condition on single array element being now in texts "table"
GROUP BY e.id
```

Comment: Thx so far. I get the ERROR: operator does not exist: texts !~~ unknown.
It seems to be the same ERROR like i got with Hambones answer.